# Problems with dynamic routes in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to use personal URLs through the code of my application that function the same way as `www.facebook.com/namehere` (on my application `www.website.com/identifier`).  How would you set this up in routes to be dynamic?  So that if `/identifier` was not an existing controller (/login, /admin, /howitworks, /about are all taken) it runs a function and uses the identifier to query a database?

I've tried reading up on routing but I can't seem to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow this url [Codeigniter's url routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) and [__remap()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping)

If your `controller` contains a function named `_remap()`, it will always get called regardless of what your URI contains. It overrides the normal behavior in which the URI determines which function is called, `allowing you to define your own function routing rules`.

Documentation of `CI` is very good, it will teach you everything in a very simple and elegent way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `404_override` in the routes config. Then checkout the `_remap` ([link](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping)) function to route things within that controller.